# New build, motherboard shows code 18 then 78

Tags: boot, motherboard, computer-building

Mother Board:Maximus VII Hero
RAM: Trident 8GB(2x)
GPU: ASUS DirectCU II
CPU: Intel i7 4990k
Power Supply: EVGA Supernova 1200W
(Don't know what I'm forgetting, I know I am though.)

So I just built a new computer after about eight hours of work using the components above. When I press the power button, everything comes on but nothing shows up on the monitor when I plug it in. Two glowing numbers on the motherboard show the code 18 then 78.

Comment: I'd check the manual to see what those codes are.

Comment: Manual mentions 4 LEDs near the top right corner that indicate which component causes a problem. Does any of them flash?

Comment: No lights flash, but the codes mean... 18:Pre-Memory system Agent initilization has started
78:ACPI Module initialization

Comment: You should use the [contact form](https://superuser.com/contact) to have your accounts merged. You'll then be able to comment on this question. Please don't post questions as answers. Those codes don't indicate errors but are normal status reports. Have you plugged the monitor into GPU or motherboard? What cable are you using?